# Sent email, without confirmation using swift (OSX)

Tags: macos, swift, email

I cannot manage to send an email using Swift on OSX.

Its almost do the work, but don't sent the email, and on my personal computer, its opening Google Chrome for some raison.

Here is my code

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSSharingServiceDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func mag(sender: AnyObject) {
        let body = "BODY EMAIL"
        let shareItems = [body] as NSArray

        var service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)
        service?.delegate = self
        service?.recipients = ["email@address.com"]

        let subject = "Subject!"
        service?.subject = subject

        service?.performWithItems(shareItems as [AnyObject])
    }          

}
```

Comment: This code works for me, it opens a Mail window as expected. Your problem is probably because you've set Chrome to be your default e-mail client instead of Apple's Mail.